# How to hook to another app's onStart on Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

How can I trigger starting my app before another app is launched?
What I need is to hook the `onStart` method of another app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the other app is being launched explicitly, there is nothing you can do to intercept this. If, however, the other app is being launched implicitly (ie: using an Intent ACTION), you can have your app also support that Intent ACTION and then, when your app is running you can launch the other app explicitly from your app.